# Solr keeps giving errors in automatic uuid generation

Tags: solr, uuid

I got a problem with automatic uuid generation in Solr. I want Solr to generate automatically uuids for the data imported by DataImportHandler.

Here's what i did:

In schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />  
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

In solrconfig.xml
I added:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">  
   <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">  
       <str name="fieldName">id</str>  
   </processor>  
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />  
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I modified:

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">  
<!-- See below for information on defining   
     updateRequestProcessorChains that can be used by name   
     on each Update Request  
  -->  
<!--  
   <lst name="defaults">  
     <str name="update.chain">dedupe</str>  
   </lst>  
   -->  
<lst name="defaults">  
    <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>  
</lst>
```

Also I did not comment or remove the UniqueKey and removed everything about QueryElevation.

But I just keep getting this error, which I totally have no idea where it comes out.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid UUID String: '1'
at org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField.toInternal(UUIDField.java:89)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.readableToIndexed(FieldType.java:393)
at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.readableToIndexed(FieldType.java:398)
at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getIndexedId(AddUpdateCommand.java:98)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:717)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:557)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:71)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:235)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:512)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:416)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:331)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:239)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:464)
```

BTW, I am using Solr 4.8.  Thanks very much for the reply and I really appreciate your help !!!

Comment: Remove the data directory and restart solr with the new configuration.

Comment: @everreadyeddy,sorry mate. That does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting field with that name coming from DIH and the UUID URP does not override one if it is present.

Try adding [IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory) in front and see if the problem goes away. If it does, you can start figuring out where DIH is picking it up from. For example, if you are getting data from the database and use *select **, DIH will automatically try to map any fields with the identical names to what you have in schema.